# Converting a pointer to an array in C++ to Java (OpenCV)

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I'm in the process of converting a function in OpenCV which is in C++ to Java. [Link.](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html)

I don't know too much about C++ and struggling to convert this part:

```
/// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
float range[] = { 0, 256 } ; //the upper boundary is exclusive
const float* histRange = { range };
```

This is what I have so far:

```
//Set of ranges
float ranges[] = {0,256};
final float histRange = {ranges};
```

**Edit:**

Thanks for your help, I have managed to get it working. This question was in the context of OpenCV (Sorry if I didn't make it clear). Code:

```
//Set of ranges
float ranges[] = {0,256};
MatOfFloat histRange = new MatOfFloat(ranges);
```

Comment: Can someone tell me what the curly braces around range is for in the C++ code?

Comment: An array of the next dimension to the array in the curly braces.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what that means and Google didn't help.

Comment: @m24p Scalar can be surrounded by optional pair of curly braces in initialization. E.g. `int a = { 5 };` is the same as `int a = 5;`

Comment: Yes, but the "ranges" variable is not a scalar. :-)

Comment: @PNS Well, my explanation was very unclear. What I meant was "when type T in `T a = { value };` is a scalar, the declaration is equal to `T a = value;`" (and `const float*` is a pointer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I have managed to get it working. This question was in the context of OpenCV (Sorry if I didn't make it clear). Code:

```
//Set of ranges
float ranges[] = {0,256};
MatOfFloat histRange = new MatOfFloat(ranges);
```

Answer (score 4):

Unless I am mistaken with my pointers today, the second line in the c++ code duplicates pointer of range, so they both point at the same pair of values. What you want in Java should be this:

```
float ranges[] = {0,256};
final float histRange[] = ranges;
```